# How can i remove signing from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

so with

```
$filestosign = (dir -recurse-include *.ps1)
Set-AuthenticodeSignature $filestosign $signingcert
```

i can sign all my ps1 files in a folder. But is there a quick way to undo this again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played a bit around and came to this solution: 
The signature is appended at the end of a file. I search for the string "SIG # Begin signature block" to know the Linenumbers i don't need any more, display the rest and write this back:

```
function remove-signature ($signedFile = "D:\ps10\test.ps1")
{
$filecontent = Get-Content $signedFile
$filecontent[0..(((Get-Content $signedFile | select-string "SIG # Begin signature block").LineNumber)-2)] | Set-Content $signedFile
}
```

Think this should work. My first thought was to find a way to select the area between the two strings: "SIG # Begin" and "SIG # End" . Just for learning purpose i would be interrested how i could have done that.

Comment: First, you don't need to call `Get-Content $signedFile` twice; you can use `$filecontent` within the array index statement. As for "finding a way to select the area between the two strings", something like this would work: `$isOutsideSig = $true; $filecontent | where { $wasOutsideSig = $isOutsideSig; if( $_.StartsWith( '# SIG #' ) ) { $isOutsideSig = -not $isOutsideSig }; $isOutsideSig -and $wasOutsideSig } | Set-Content $signedFile`

Comment: This broke some scripts I had that didn't have digital signatures. Use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Remove-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet, but you can create one using something like this:

```
function Remove-AuthenticodeSignature {
    param (
        [string]$Path
    )

    $fileContent = Get-Content $Path
    $signatureLine = $fileContent | Select-String "SIG # Begin signature block"

    if ($null -eq $signatureLine) {
        Write-Host "No signature block found in file: $Path"
        return
    }

    $lineNumber = $signatureLine.LineNumber - 2
    $newContent = $fileContent[0..$lineNumber]
    $newContent | Set-Content $Path
}
```

When testing the other solution similar to this one, I discovered that it removed the majority of the script. I personally tested this function on my own signed scripts and can confirm it functions as intended.